# Ветвление в логике

Tags: python, selenium

Мне нужно на selenium python сделать условие, например:

> - если на странице есть определенный текст, то он выполняет дальнейшие действия
> - если через поиск на странице текста нет, то он возвращается на предыдущую страницу.

Подскажите, как?

Comment: Ну сделайте. С чем возникла проблема?

Answer (score 0):

Нашел информацию на [форуме Хабра](https://qna.habr.com/q/624628).
Попробуйте сделать так:

```
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException

try:
     elem = driver.find_element_by_id('text') # находим нужный элемент
     # прописываете дальнейшие действия

# если не можем найти элемент
except NoSuchElementException:
    driver.get('ссылка на предыдущую страницу')
```